# setText from another class will open another windows

Tags: java, settext

(Sorry for bad English)
I am trying to edit the JLabel from another class and it success but i found a problem that once it edit the text, it will open another window.

How can fix it?

Code:

Menu.java:

```
package Demo1;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.ColorType;
import java.awt.Window.Type;

public class Menu extends JFrame {
    JFrame f;
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        new Menu();
        Sdle();
    }
    public static void Sdle() {
        Timer Timer = new Timer();
        Timer.schedule(new ServerPing(), 1, 120000);

    }
    public Font nmFont(Integer Size) {
        Font NewFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, Size);
        return NewFont;
    }
    public void setSerLabel(String CT){
        ServerStatusLb.setText(CT);
    }
    public void setClockLabel(String CT1){
        ClockLb.setText(CT1);
    }
    private JLabel ClockLb = new JLabel("Timer",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel ServerStatusLb = new JLabel("New label",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    public Menu(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        f=new JFrame("Menu");
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(470,345);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Container cp=f.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(null);

        ClockLb.setBounds(0, 0, 454, 75);
        ClockLb.setFont(nmFont(66));
        cp.add(ClockLb);

        ServerStatusLb.setBounds(153, 79, 160, 31);
        ServerStatusLb.setFont(nmFont(20));
        cp.add(ServerStatusLb);
    }
}
```

And ClockMa.java (Manage the clock label):

```
package Demo1;

import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClockMa extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //可用: YY, MM, DD, HH, mm, ss
        Date date = new Date();
        Menu MN = new Menu();
        MN.setClockLabel(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not setting the text that makes a window open: it's `new Menu()`. Because the `Menu()` constructor makes a `JFrame` and calls `f.setVisible(true)`. Are you sure you want to make a new `Menu` in your timer task?

Comment: You should explain why you need the class *ClockMa* to change the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Menu()` creates a new menu every time `run()` runs. Rather, create an instance of the menu outside the `run()` operation and set the label text in the `run()` operation

Comment: How to "create an instance of the menu outside the `run()`"?